# VBA Match to C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, vba

I'm converting Excel VBA to C# (using a VSTO project in Visual Studio .NET). The bellow code is puzzling me, since there are no similar function in C#.

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(stringA, Range(stringB), 0)
If result = 0 Then DoStuff
```

How can I replicate the above functionality in C#?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(stringA, Range(stringB), 0);
if (iTemp_result == 0) 
{
    DoStuff();      
}
```

Comment: Actually I couldnt get the Application.WorksheetFunction.Match to work.. but your simple direction opened my eyes:)